# merging branches after moving files to a different directory

Tags: git, git-merge, git-mv

I have two branches that I try to merge. In the original branch I have some files that in the 2nd branch where moved to a different location. the problem is that when I try to merge from the original branch, it doesn't apply the changes to the new file location even tough it detected that I moved the files with `git move`.

I created the following scenario to better explain my problem:

I have branch `a` with files `a/1.txt`, `a/2.txt`. in branch `b` I did `git mv` to `1.txt` and `2.txt` from directory `a` to `b`.

next.. in branch `a` I modified `a/1.txt`, in branch `b` when I try merge branch `a` into it, it tries to create `a/1.txt` instead of applying the change on the new file's location (in directory `b`).

how do I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I provided a small example that most probably shows your problem:

```
mkdir test
cd test/
git init
echo -e '1\n2\n3' >foo
git add foo
git commit -m foo
git checkout -b bar
echo -e '1\n4\n5' >bar
rm foo
git add --all .
git commit -m bar
git checkout -
echo -e '6\n2\n3' >foo
git add foo
git commit -m foo2
git merge bar
```

Now you get an error saying

```
# CONFLICT (modify/delete): foo deleted in bar and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of foo left in tree.
# Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

If you instead decrease the level of similarity that is necessary to identify a rename with `-X find-renames=30%` (similarity was 33%, as one of three lines was the same), the merge works better:

```
git merge --abort
git merge bar -X find-renames=30%
git mergetool
git commit --no-edit
```